# How to incline UIImageView in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have displayed a series of images in a coverflow effect.

But, now i want them in an inclined format, so that they have to appear as ray emerging from a point.

Can anyone please give me any suggestions, or any samples regarding my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the image should look like...

[image]